# Oracle Trigger with Multiple sequences filled on condition with relation to another sequence and column value

Tags: oracle, oracle12c, database-trigger

I have table to classifying Products as below

```
   Category_ID     VARCHAR2 (1024)  NOT NULL, --PK
   Category_Desc   VARCHAR2 (1024)  NOT NULL,
   Class1_ID       VARCHAR2 (1024),
   Class1_Desc     VARCHAR2 (1024),
   Class2_ID       VARCHAR2 (1024),
   Class2_Desc     VARCHAR2 (1024),
   Class3_ID       VARCHAR2 (1024),
   Class3_Desc     VARCHAR2 (1024),
   Notes           VARCHAR2 (1024),
```

column `Category_ID` filled by sequence `Seq_Category_ID` using trigger now 
what I want to do is

- filling column `Class1_ID` with value of column `Category_ID` concatenate with 
  it is sequence names `Seq_Class1_ID`
- filling column `Class2_ID` with value of column `Category_ID` concatenate with `Class1_ID` concatenate with it is sequence names `Seq_Class2_ID`

and so on...

but I am getting error on that says

> [Error] PLS-00103 (11: 4): PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "{" when
>   expecting one of the following:
>
> ( begin case declare exit for goto if loop mod null pragma    raise
>   return select update while with
>
> mod       continue current sql execute forall merge [Error]
>   PLS-00103 (13: 2): PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "}" when
>   expecting one of the following:
>
> ( begin case declare else elsif end exit for goto if loop mod
>   null pragma raise return select update while with

finally

**Is there any better way to manage the case I am talking about ?**

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER Trg_Category_ID_Seq
   BEFORE INSERT
   ON Product_Classification
   FOR EACH ROW
   WHEN (NEW.Category_ID IS NULL)
BEGIN

   :NEW.Category_ID := Seq_Category_ID.NEXTVAL;

   IF(NEW.Class1_Desc IS NOT NULL AND NEW.Category_ID IS NOT NULL AND NEW.Class1_ID IS NULL ) THEN
   {
    INSERT INTO Product_Classification (Class1_ID)VALUES(NEW.Category_ID||Seq_Class1_ID.NEXTVAL);
    }

END;
```

Answer (score 1):

When working with `if conditions` in block statements(or triggers) no need to use `{}` you close it with `end if;`

this way will fix your issue

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER Trg_Category_ID_Seq
   BEFORE INSERT
   ON Product_Classification
   FOR EACH ROW

when (NEW.Category_ID IS NULL)
BEGIN

   :NEW.Category_ID := Seq_Category_ID.NEXTVAL;


   IF(NEW.Class1_Desc IS NOT NULL AND NEW.Category_ID IS NOT NULL AND NEW.Class1_ID IS NULL ) THEN

    INSERT INTO Product_Classification (Class1_ID)VALUES(NEW.Category_ID||Seq_Class1_ID.NEXTVAL);
   end if;

END;
```

Comment: thanks ... is there any better way to mange the case I am talking about ?

Answer (score 1):

The syntax issues in your code:

- the way you handle the `IF THEN` block, as said
- you're missing some `':'` while using `NEW` instead of `:NEW`.

How it should be:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER Trg_Category_ID_Seq
   BEFORE INSERT
   ON Product_Classification
   FOR EACH ROW
   WHEN (NEW.Category_ID IS NULL)
BEGIN

   :NEW.Category_ID := Seq_Category_ID.NEXTVAL;

   IF(:NEW.Class1_Desc IS NOT NULL AND :NEW.Category_ID IS NOT NULL AND :NEW.Class1_ID IS NULL ) THEN

    INSERT INTO Product_Classification (Class1_ID)VALUES(:NEW.Category_ID||Seq_Class1_ID.NEXTVAL);
   END IF;

END;
```